# Does one row of background wall stop monster spawning?

Tags: terraria

Consider this platform:

[image: image description]

It has one row of cactus wall right behind it. Does that stop monsters from spawning on it? I'm looking for simple way to restrict monster spawns over large area and this looks viable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any player-placed wall will prevent the game from selecting the tile in front of it to spawn a monster. However once a tile is selected, the game will then select the ground right below that tile to actually spawn the monster, even if the tile at ground level has a wall in front of it, so if you want to only use walls, you'll have to cover 47 tiles above ground, as detailed [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC_spawning#Spawning_Basics).

Another way to stop spawns is simply to build many NPC houses. Each NPC in an area will lower the spawn chance and monster cap, and when you have 3 or 4, no monsters will be able to spawn at all, except for special events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the wall was placed by you or another player. Naturally spawning walls, like in caves, do not prevent monster spawning. Also, if you wish to also prevent the spawning of flying monsters, then you will need to cover your ENTIRE world with walls, since flying monsters can spawn at any height.

Comment: This answer seems to be in contradiction to the answer above it.